# how to set table tr background color according to same value in php

Tags: php, css, mysql

how can i set the table tr background color according to same value in one row ?

```
<?php 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `status` where username ='".$UserName."' ",$conn);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '
    <tr style="'.$bgcolor.'">
        <td>
        '.$row["Uv"].'
        </td>
        <td>
        '.$row["Su"].'
        </td>
        <td> '.$row["Status"].' </td>
    </tr> ';
}
?>
```

[How the rows should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9m2P.png)
i wan't change color according to same uv like hmsid20161812(blue color), hmsid20161815(brown color), hmsid20161810 (yellow color) means we give color code or name in array but print according to uv.

Comment: `<tr style="background-color: '.$bgcolor.'">`

Comment: will "Su" come in any order

Comment: Where is `$bgcolor` defined? From where will it get different color values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `background-color:` attribute of css before colour.

Change

```
<tr style="'.$bgcolor.'">
```

with

```
<tr style="background-color: '.$bgcolor.'">
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this and you should also change all your `mysql_` functions to at least `mysqli_` functions. Better try PDO. Have a look at this awasome blog [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

```
<?php

$bgcolor = "blue"; //you have to define it somewhere like here
$bgcolor2 = "red"; //you have to define it somewhere like here
$bgcolor3 = "yellow"; //you have to define it somewhere like here

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `status` where username ='".$UserName."' ",$conn);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['Uv'] == "hmsid20161812") {
        echo "<tr style='background-color: $bgcolor'>
                <td>
                ".$row['Uv']."
                </td>
                <td>
                ".$row["Su"]."
                </td>
                <td> ".$row["Status"]." </td>
            </tr> ";
    } elseif ($row['Uv'] == "hmsid20161815") {
        echo "<tr style='background-color: $bgcolor2'>
                <td>
                ".$row['Uv']."
                </td>
                <td>
                ".$row["Su"]."
                </td>
                <td> ".$row["Status"]." </td>
            </tr> ";
    }
    elseif ($row['Uv'] == "hmsid20161810") {
        echo "<tr style='background-color: $bgcolor3'>
                <td>
                ".$row['Uv']."
                </td>
                <td>
                ".$row["Su"]."
                </td>
                <td> ".$row["Status"]." </td>
            </tr> ";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Blueblazer172 but We can not set manually like this because it is lot of uv.....

Comment: define an array with all names of the row and then make `if elseif` statements